# How to get a dynamic excel sheet out of a list, based on a value of a column

Tags: excel

I think I need to solve this with an array formula in Excel, but I am kind of stucked.
Imagine you have an excel sheet (called main_data).
In here you have a list of people and a status for each person.

```
||Name(Column A)||Age (Column B)||Status (Column C)||
|Albert|10|New|  
|Benjamin|20|New|    
|Carlos|30|Old|    
|Denis|40|New|
```

Now I want on the second sheet, that only the records are shown under each other that have the status "new". (but actually without showing the status column)
Like this

```
||Name(Column A)||Age (Column B)||Status (Column C)||
|Albert|10|    
|Benjamin|20|    
|Denis|40|
```

A couple of things:
- I do not want to use a pivot table, as the second sheet, which is my required end result, as it must be in a very specific format and order
- I do not want to use an autofilter. (I could add the status column in sheet 2, filter by status new and hide the column. Once I add or remove a record in sheet 1, I have to repeat that filter process)

Any ideas?
Can I do this somehow with an Array formula and add an if condition for the status column?

I tried normal IF function, index / match and Array. but none of them worked as I wanted.

This on sheet 1:

```
||Name(Column A)||Age (Column B)||Status (Column C)||    
|Albert|10|New|    
|Benjamin|20|New|    
|Carlos|30|Old|    
|Denis|40|New|
```

turns into this on sheet 2, but dynamically, without any user interaction:

```
||Name(Column A)||Age (Column B)||Status (Column C)||    
|Albert|10|    
|Benjamin|20|    
|Denis|40|
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is thus. If your source data are in Sheet1

[image]

then in Sheet2 put this formula in A2 and copy down and across as far as necessary. Adjust ranges to suit. It's an array formula so confirm with Ctrl+Shift+Enter and curly brackets will appear round the formula.

> =IF(ROWS(A$2:A2)<=COUNTIF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5,"New"),INDEX(Sheet1!$A$2:$C$5,SMALL(IF(Sheet1!$C$2:$C$5="New",ROW($A$2:$A$5)-ROW($A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2)),COLUMNS($A$2:A2)),"")

[image]